# How to showvariable with gitversion Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, gitversion

I can successfully get the full json string with:

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:`pwd` gittools/gitversion-dotnetcore:linux-4.0.0 `pwd` -output json
```

which outputs to something like:

```
{
  "Major":0,
  "Minor":1,
  "Patch":0,
  "SemVer":"0.1.0-dev-2.1",
.
.
.
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource":20,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded":"0020",
  "CommitDate":"2020-05-28"
}
```

Since I am only interested in `SemVer` variable I try to use the `-showvariable FullSemVer` with:

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:`pwd` gittools/gitversion-dotnetcore:linux-4.0.0 `pwd` -output json -showvariable FullSemVer
```

But it fails with a quite long and nasty error log.

```
INFO [05/28/20 18:23:12:10] End: Loading version variables from disk cache (Took: 76.31ms)
ERROR [05/28/20 18:23:12:13] An unexpected error occurred:
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

I wonder if there is a way to use the `-showvariable` flag with the `gitversion` Docker container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the path argument passed to GitVersion. `pwd` will give you the working directory on your host, not within the container. GitVersion is unfortunately not aware of the fact that it's executing within a container, so it needs to be provided with the volume directory `/repo` as the path to calculate a version number for. This is something we should consider changing in version 6.

I also can't remember when `-showvariable` was implemented, so to be on the safe side you should try with a [newer version of our Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/layers/gittools/gitversion/5.3.4-linux-alpine.3.10-x64-netcoreapp3.1/images/sha256-f1261e13f82effa4c5336b3e2e59dce986d010ad41acc773b1aa0ef95e8fcd0a?context=explore). I can also recommend using the `alpine` container, as it's the smallest one we offer (only 83.9 MB). This works:

```sh
docker run \
    --rm \
    --volume "$(pwd):/repo" \
    gittools/gitversion:5.3.4-linux-alpine.3.10-x64-netcoreapp3.1 \
    /repo \
    -output json \
    -showvariable FullSemVer
```